# How do I publish a private app in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I need to upload an internal app for a customer. This will be used only in the scope of the company, so i don't need it to be public. Is there a way to publish a private app in Google Play Store, so I can share it only with pre-determined users?

Comment: There is a bunch of tutorials on internet for that.
I don't think you are the good place here

Comment: I've been doing research but nothing useful so far, sometimes outdated solutions. Any links @JimmyFraiture ?

Comment: You can publish it to a closed alpha track, available just to specific testers. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming but instead to a specific service’s publishing mechanism and policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution) if the company you work for is small. Thus, you can send an invitation to the person you want by adding their e-mail. Also, google play has a doc like [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization)